# vim: highlight words in visual block mode

Tags: vim

Below is a screenshot of me entering visual block mode and pressing "w" to select by word:

[image]

How can I select every word in the rows I have selected? Meaning I want the full word in the rows highlighted instead of it getting cut off as shown in the screenshot.

edit: What I want to be able to do is delete a column of words of varying length. In the example screenshot I want to delete the words between the  tags, But it could be any column of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of plugins for multiple selection, look them up on vim.org.

But I must remind you that visually selecting text is more often than not an unnecessary step. Why don't you explain what you actually want to achieve instead of your failed attempts? Maybe there's a better way...

[edit]

```
:'<,'>norm dit
```

seems to be the simplest way to achieve your goal *without* selecting every word:

[image: animated GIF]

and `:,+7norm dit` would be even better because you don't select *anything*.

Answer (score 2):

The highlight modes can only select blocks (by cursor, by line, or by rectangular block).  You can use a plugin such as [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where Vim allows a non-rectangular, "jagged edge" visual selection is *at the end of the lines*, i.e. by extending the blockwise selection with `$`. Therefore, you'd need to (temporarily) get rid of the trailing `</th>` (or include it in the selection, but operate in such a way that they are kept intact).

You shouldn't *need* a selection to work with the text. For example, to *delete* the text inside the tags, you can use a substitution:

```
:%s#<th>\zs.*\ze</th>##
```

Comment: What I want to be able to do is delete a column of words of varying length. In the example screenshot I want to delete the words between the <th> tags, But it could be any column of words.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I've added an example for deletion to my answer.

Comment: That was just an example. I'd like to be able to delete every word in a selected column, not just between html tags. Like every word the cursor touches in visual block mode.

Comment: By adapting the regular expression, you can achieve that, too; regexp's are very powerful (but of course, there's a point of complexity where it stops making sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only select rectangular blocks in block select mode. Maybe a plugin solves this?

Comment: Is this simple enough to a autocmd for? If so what would that look like?